# Two cards are drawn from 52−card deck (the first is not replaced)

Tags: probability

Two cards are drawn from 52−card deck (the first is not replaced)

(a) given the first card a queen, what is the probability that the second is also a queen?
(b) Repeat part (a) for the first card a queen and the second card is 7
(c) What is the probability that both cards will be a queen?

Comment: This should be no different than a problem with a bag of marbles of various colors.  The approach involves taking ratios and introductory applications of conditional probability and product rule.  For the first problem for instance... the question can be rephrased "Suppose you have a bag with $51$ marbles, three of which are red, what is the probability of drawing a red marble from this bag?"  I should hope you can answer the rephrased version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) So after we choose the first queen, we are left with $51$ cards with three queens in them, So then the probability that we get a queen should be:$\frac{3}{51}$

b)Here after we choose the first queen, we are left with $51$ cards with four $7$ in them, hence the probability that we get a $7$ is :$\frac{4}{51} $

c)Here we are picking 2 cards from a deck of $52$ cards, so there are $52*51$ possible outcomes. There are $\binom{4}{2}=\frac{4*3}{2}$ ways to get choose $2$ queens from $4$ queens and the order of choice matters, so we should get $4*3$ ways to choose ordered pair of queens, hence the probability that we get two queens is: $\frac{4}{52}\frac{3}{51}$

Comment: Only numerical answers without any explanation whatsoever (*even if the explanation seems obvious to you or me*) don't help the question asker learn how to answer this on their own in the future.